# WebService memory usage when hosted in CassiniDev after rebuild

Tags: .net, wcf, memory-management

I have got a WCF service which takes up quote some memory, around 1GB.

Its hosted locally in development asp.net hosting (CassiniDev).

When I make a change in code and hit build, server doesn't stop working. It actually starts to use updated code seamlessly, except for memory.

From what it appears it just doubles memory usage after rebuild, so I am not quite sure whats going on here. I have got rather little memory on my machine so sometimes this causes total system freeze.

I am wondering why doesn't it run some GC collect once it starts updating dlls for example, cause doubling memory size def sounds like something interesting is going on. And obviously after its rebuilt, there is no way to access previous version of service anymore, so it would make sense to me if it would not double memory usage, but use the same instead.

EDIT: I guess this could be generalized to memory management when we push an updated dll to service directory, for IIS hosted services and development too.

Comment: Sounds like you have a memory leak. Maybe you've got requests which are still being processed by the original Cassini, so a new one is started up after you rebuild. The memory would still be in use for the original.

Comment: Its a local service which is only used by me with infrequent requests. When I hit rebuild I am positive that nothing is being executed. If this sounds like a memory leak to you, how dou you think service memory usage should really look like, like graph shape? I would assume its expected to look something like this V shape going pretty low to memory usage, but in my experience its not that way. its kinda _/ shape instead. Oh and everything is managed and I am not sure what kind of memory leak this could be. As for memory use, its huge lookup tables that take up space.

Comment: I would try killing Cassini in between builds to see if that solves the problem. If it doesn't, then something else is going on. You may also want to proactively switch to IIS Express, as Visual Studio 2012 removes Cassini.

Comment: Killing Cassini between builds is what I am currently doing, yep. I was just wondering about inner mechanics of process that I describe in question. Moving to IIS sounds like a problem solution for me, but not an explanation of behaviour, which is quite curious imo.